# Why are there 8 elements in Galois ring problem?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, quotient-spaces

Here is the problem:

```
R=GF(2)[x]  mod  x^3 + 1 = 0
```

Now, I know these are the 8 elements in it.

0, 1, x, x+1, x<sup>2</sup>, x<sup>2</sup>  + 1, x<sup>2</sup> + x, x<sup>2</sup> + x + 1

According to the question I asked here: [Constructing add/multi tables for GF(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432624/constructing-add-multi-tables-for-gf2/1433064?noredirect=1#comment2920638_1433064)

**The 8 elements come from any element in GF(2)[x] divided by x^3 + 1. Then there are 8 possible remainders, and those remainders are the 8 elements.**

I don't understand this though. If 0 is an element, and I divide that by x^3 + 1, I get 0 as an answer, with no remainder. Where are these 8 remainders coming from? Does the amount of remainders change if instead of x^3 + 1, it was x^4 + 1, or x^3 + x + 1?

Answer (score 1):

‘No remainder’ means a remainder equal to $0$.

The remainders are all the polynomials of degree at most $2$ in $\mathbf F_2[x]$:
$$\{0,1,x, x^2, 1+x, 1+x^2, x+x^2,1+x+x^2\}.$$

For $x^3+x+1$ it would be the same, but the Cayley tables for multiplication would be different.

For $x^4+1$ as well as for $x^3+1$, you don't obtain a field, because the polynomials are not irreducible, as pointed @fkraiem 4:
$$x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2,\quad x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1).$$

Comment: Oh, so why are they called remainders then? What is being divided to get those remainders?

Comment: You take *every* polynomial in $GF(2)[x]$, and try dividing it by $x^3 + 1$. Even though you're trying infinitely many dividends, you end up with only $8$ distinct remainders.

Comment: @pfinferno: it is like congruence classes in $\mathbf Z$. You partition the set of polynomials into $8$ classes, according to their remainder upon division by $x^3+1$.

Comment: $x^3+1 = (x^2-x+1)(x+1)$ is not irreducible over $\mathbf{F}_2$ either (or indeed over any field). ;)

Comment: Oops! What a stupid mistake! I'll correct that at once. Thank you for pointing it.

Comment: Okay that makes sense now! One question though, I can still make an addition/multiplication table for x^3 + 1 and x^4 + 1? Why isn't x^3 + 1 reducible over any field?

Comment: Oh wait, they have to be irreducible for it?

Comment: You'all always have a multiplication table, but you obtain a field only if the polynomial is irreducible. As pointed by @frkaiem $x^3+1$ is reducible over any field.

Comment: I have a question that says to construct the addition and multiplication tables for those 3 rings. So those 8 elements wouldn't work for x^4 +1 and x^3 + 1? (Can take this to discussion if you want). I see that they aren't irreducible, but don't know what why that is important regarding construction of those tables.

Comment: Whether  irreducible or not is unimportant for the tables construction. The $8$ elements work for all polynomials of degree $3$, but the products will not be the same. As for $x^4+1$, you will need the $16$ polynomials of degree $<4$.

Comment: Oh I see now, that makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is "@fkraiem 4"denoting some variant of fkraiem ? Should it be "as pointed out by fkraiem ?"